# Google Apps Script sends wrong form input via mail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am pretty new to coding and have the following problem with my little Google Apps Script.

Can anyone tell me why the following script doesn't send me/the user (I use the form and this script only myself) the specific answer of my latest form response? It somehow always sends me the answer of the form response with which I used this script the first time...

```
function sendAnswerViaMail() {

  var myEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = 'My answer to the 26th question.';
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var itemResponse = itemResponses[25];
  MailApp.sendEmail (myEmail, subject, itemResponse.getResponse());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your script is fired when a user submit the form via the trigger functionnality.
The approach you have here is more logic one, but unfortunatelly not the good one because it does not handle the fact that 2 people may answer your form in almost the same time and the trigger that launch your script is not correlated with the fact that your script has recorded the answer and that you can access it with:

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
```

Instead of that approach I can propose you to use the object that the trigger on form submit will give to your function when launched:

```
/**
* function triggered each time the form is submited
*
*/
function submitFormFunc(e) { 
  var user = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();

  var responses={}; // given responses form the user
  var respObj = {};
  for(var i = 0; i< items.length; i++) {
    var it = items[i];
    responses[it.getItem().getId()] = {
      "title":it.getItem().getTitle(),
      "response":it.getResponse()
    };
    respObj[it.getItem().getTitle()] = it.getResponse();
  }
  Logger.log("responses: "+JSON.stringify(responses));
}
```